# Disable auto-escaping in WTForms SelectField

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am trying to show an additional html item in the list of choices of a `SelectField` from WTForms:

```
languages = [('en', '<i class="en flag">English'),
             ('de', '<i class="de flag">Deutsch')]

pref_language = SelectField(choices=languages)
```

The html tags always get escaped automatically, even if wrapped in `HTMLString(...)`:

```
<option value="en">&lt;i class="en flag"&gt;English</option>
<option value="de">&lt;i class="de flag"&gt;Deutsch</option>
```

**Update:**

I narrowed the problem down to [this line in WTForms](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/widgets/core.py#L313):

```
return HTMLString('<option %s>%s</option>' % (html_params(**options), escape(text_type(label), quote=False)))
```

Unfortunately I don't see a way to fix this externally.

Comment: You may try to add a custom widget to SelectField (http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/widgets.html#custom-widgets)

Comment: In my understanding, the call of the escape-method is a little bit too deep to just get around it using a custom widget. I just opened a new issue on GitHub (https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/issues/301)

Comment: It's Jinja/itsdangerous that escapes the HTML. You should use Jinja markup to mark that html as `|safe` [Link to docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/wtforms/#forms-in-templates)

Comment: Actually it's not. I 'fixed' this in my fork and requested a pull. (https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/pull/302)